# How to add image a spinner in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

how can I add images to each item of my spinner.

My code:

```
 val lista = arrayOf("Kotlin","Python","Java","Mongodb","GoLand","C++")
        val adaptador = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,lista)
        spinner.adapter = adaptador
        when(spinner.selectedItem.toString()){
            "Koltin" -> Toast.makeText(this,"Kotiin",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            "Python" -> Toast.makeText(this,"Python",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            "Java" -> Toast.makeText(this,"Java",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            "Mongodb" -> Toast.makeText(this,"Mongodb",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            "GoLand" -> Toast.makeText(this,"GoLand",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            "C++" -> Toast.makeText(this,"C++",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible to add a picture with the normal spinner , if you want to add an image to spinner , you will need to make a custom class "Custom Spinner"

Comment: How do I do it in koltin?

Comment: I solved my question with this tutorial.l:https://dzone.com/articles/custom-spinner-for-android-application